# Bash script : Unexpected End Of File (FreeBSD)

Tags: bash, freebsd

I got a task to create a bash script to install Subversion scheduler on my freebsd machine, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

when I run

```
#bash -x ./installSubversion.sh
```

I always got this error messages

```
+ REPOPATH=$'/usr/ports/devel/subversion\r'
+ CHECKPATH=$'/usr/local/bin/svnserve\r'
>./installSubversion.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

here is the script installSubversion.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
###########
### Installing subversion(svn) on Freebsd
###########
REPOPATH="/usr/ports/devel/subversion"
CHECKPATH="/usr/local/bin/svnserve"
if [ ! -x "$CHECKPATH"  ] || [ "$1" = "-force" ] ;
then
        echo "Trying to install subversion from ports"
        if [ "$1" = "-force"  ];
        then
                /usr/sbin/pkg_delete -fx subversion-
                cd $REPOPATH
                /usr/bin/make -DBATCH reinstall clean
        else
                cd $REPOPATH
                /usr/bin/make -DBATCH install clean
        fi
else
        echo "subversion is Installed"
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue, but it is not necessary to have both a semicolon (`;`) and a newline before the `then` part of an `if` statement. Have you deleted the inner `if ... fi` to try and get the same error message?

Comment: @Anthon  I think that is everything to do with it, `fi\r` does not end an if

Comment: @Jasen AFIAK you can insert them and leave them out if the `then` is on the next line. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Jasen: Fair point. Some may consider it a bug that bash doesn't ignore `\r` at the end of a line, others consider it a feature. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages `REPOPATH=$'/usr/ports/devel/subversion\r'` indicate that your script has DOS-style line endings `\r\n` instead of Unix-style `\n`. That can be fixed with a simple `sed` command, or using the [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) command, which you may have already installed on your system.

Your text editor may have an option to select line ending style. If so, make sure you use Unix-style when editing scripts for use in *nix. And you can use such an  editor to convert the line ending style of existing files, but that can be a bit tedious if you want to fix multiple files.

Comment: looks to me the good answer, along with no ; in if statement.